# Calling enums in another class in C++

Tags: c#, c++, enums

If we define two C++ classes. One is:

```
abstract class A {
  public:
    enum E {F, G, H;}
};
```

Another is class B, and how I can use the enum E in class A then? Assuming both B and A are in  the same namespace. I know in C# we can use something like:

```
A.E
```

directly, but seems that is not the case of C++.

Comment: `abstract`? `public:`? Is that C++ or C#?

Comment: `#define abstract /*nothing*/` of course!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, `.` and `->` are for accessing a member of this particular instance of an `A` object. `::` is for accessing things in the scope of class `A`. This includes statics, enums, and function pointers.

So in C++ you want `A::F` or `A::G` if you want enum value.

for the enum type you do `A::E`

```
class A
{
public:
    enum E { F , G , H};
    virtual ~A() = 0; //a pure virtual function to make the class abstract
};

int main()
{
    A::E x; // x is declared as the enum
    x = A::F; // x is assigned a particular enum value

    return 0;
}
```

Also to make the class abstract you provide a **pure virtual function**.

Comment: Added a concept that I thought was meaningful and missing from your otherwise good answer.

Comment: @MD.. Thanks... I hope from my anwser it is clear that you don't do `A::E::F` which is common mistake

Comment: As of C++11, that is now allowed. (And I've always done that anyway, since MSVC allowed it as an extension)

Answer (score 1):

C# has single `.` operator.
C++ has multiple: `.`, `->` and `::`.
For classes you use the last one.

Therefore, it is going to be `A::E`.

Remember also, that in C++ the enum's constant go to parent namespace, not the one of enum like it is in C#. Therefore, in C# you would have `A.E.F`, but in C++ you have `A::F`.

Comment: I was just curious to know why destructor was made pure virtual function?

Comment: It is more of a question to the answer above. But I guess this is a way to prevent class from being instantiated. Never used that myself though.